# MODIS - runGdal - error in strsplit: non character argument

Tags: gdal, r, modis

I'm using the MODIS package, but am running into the following error:

```
Error in strsplit(x, ":") : non-character argument
```

See code below:

```
getT = getTile(tileH = 26, tileV = 4)
tfs = runGdal(job = "NDVI", product = "MOD13Q1", begin = "2000.02.18", end = "2000.03.10", extent = getT)
tfs
```

I've tried a few sample codes online that should work without issue, but keep getting the same error. Does anyone know where this is coming from?